# Check if object_id occurs more than once in queryset.annotate Case When parameter

Tags: python, django, django-1.11

Documentation field look up doesn't really help in my case

What my query looks like now

```py
date_delta = 2

queryset = TrendData.objects.filter(owner__trend_type__mnemonic='posts', 
 date_trend__date__range=[date_from, date_to]).values('owner_id', 'owner__name')

queryset.annotate(owner_name=F('owner_id__name')).values('owner_name', 'owner_id').annotate(
    views = Sum(Case(When(owner_id__gt=1, then=F('views') / date_delta)), default=('views')...,
                output_field=IntegerField() )
)
```

the `queryset` output looks like this:

```py
{'owner_id': 1306, 'owner__name': 'Some name123'}, 
{'owner_id': 1307, 'owner__name': 'Somename as well'}, 
{'owner_id': 1308, 'owner__name': 'aand another name'}, 
{'owner_id': 1306, 'owner__name': 'Some name123'}
```

as you can see there are matching owner_id's and the queryset len() is 100k per day, so if range of dates is 5 days queryset len() == 500k.
my models.py look like this

```py
class Owner(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Objects'

    TREND_OWNERS = Choices('group', 'user')

    link = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    owner_type = models.CharField(choices=TREND_OWNERS, max_length=50)
    trend_type = models.ForeignKey(TrendType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.link}[{self.trend_type}]'


class TrendData(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Trends'

    owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    views = models.IntegerField()
    views_u = models.IntegerField()
    likes = models.IntegerField()
    shares = models.IntegerField()
    interaction_rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=10)
    mean_age = models.IntegerField()
    date_trend = models.DateTimeField()
```

I realised that it will work fine, but it will be wrong, since if owner_id is great it will divide by date_delta, where in my case I want if owner_id occurence  in queryset more than once. I have tried `owner_id__count__gt` but that doesnt exist :(

I would love to know if there is a way to count owner_id occurence in my annotate `Case(When())` queryset. that will literally solve my problem.
if it's greater than 1 than we divide by date_delta, else we leave it as it is

**Update:**

Just to be clear, this annotation does an excellent job, however it also divides some queries that i don't want to be divided (in my case NON duplicate owner_id queryset still divides it's views, shares etc by 2) so that is why I use Case(When()) mentioned above

```py
queryset.values('owner__name', 'owner_id').annotate(
    views=Sum('views') / 2, 
    views_u=Sum('views_u') / 2, 
    likes=Sum('likes') / 2,
    shares=Sum('shares') / 2, 
    interaction_rate=Sum('interaction_rate') / 2,
    mean_age=Sum('mean_age') / 2)
```

**UPDATE #2**
This is my logic but in python

```py
json_output = []
for item in (queryset
                .values('owner__name', 'owner_id')
                .annotate(owner_count=Count('owner_id'))
                .annotate(views=Sum('views'), views_u=Sum('views_u'),
                            likes=Sum('likes'),
                            shares=Sum('shares'),
                            interaction_rate=Sum('interaction_rate'),
                            mean_age=Sum('mean_age')):
    if item['owner_count'] > 1:
        item['views'] = item['views'] / date_delta
        item['views_u'] = item['views_u'] / date_delta
        item['likes'] = item['likes'] / date_delta
        item['shares'] = item['shares'] / date_delta
        item['interaction_rate'] = '{:.10f}'.format(
            Decimal(item['interaction_rate']) / date_delta)
        item['mean_age'] = item['mean_age'] / date_delta
        json_output.append(item)
    else:
        json_output.append(item)
```

Comment: What is the end goal of this query? owners with more than one trend data?

Comment: @Sayse the end goal is to sum all the views of trenddata.objects and if there are more than 1 owner in those objects divide it by date_delta(2 in our case) if not just leave the sum as it is

Comment: There never will be more than one owner though as it is a foreign key rather than a many to many relationship

Comment: My queryset (TrendData) is range of dates example :
```<QuerySet [{'id': 275369, 'owner_id': 155116, 'views': 19882, 'views_u': 13351, 'likes': 71, 'shares': 5, 'interaction_rate': Decimal('0.005692457300000'), 'mean_age': 31, 'source_id': 3, 'date_trend': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 6, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)}, {'id': 275370, 'owner_id': 155116, 'views': 15280, 'views_u': 13351, 'likes': 160, 'shares': 10, 'interaction_rate': Decimal('0.012733128900000'), 'mean_age': 32, 'source_id': 3, 'date_trend': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 5, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)}```
there are more than 2 owners in 1 queryset

Comment: So you're looking for an aggregation of views rather than an annotation?

Comment: @Sayse nope, nnotation, aggregation will give me just a sum of all views etc
annotation will give me for each of the objects that have common owners ( IF i m not mistaken tho)

Comment: @Sayse I have updated my question once again with an example of an 'almost' working code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:
Turns out that I hadn't tested this fully after all (I thought I had, apologies). You need to have the `Case` wrapped around `Sum`, the other way around (`Sum` around `Case`) won't work no matter the Django version:

```
(queryset
    .values('owner', owner_name=F('owner__name'))
    .annotate(owner_count=Count('owner'))
    .annotate(views = Case(
        When(owner_count__gt=1,
             then=Sum(F('views') / date_delta)),
        default=Sum('views'),
        output_field=IntegerField()
    ))
)
```

A slight variation would be to use a subquery. Raydel's subquery that calculates the `Trenddata` count for every `Owner` works in principle, but will be prohibitively slow as it does an aggregation for every single row in `Trenddata` (not just for unique `Owner`s).

A different subquery provides a faster way of getting the same result. It does the heavy lifting of counting `Owner`s in `Trenddata` only once and then checks for every `Trenddata` object if its owner is in the list. I would think this should still be slower than my first query, but strangely enough, it came out on par in my short tests (with around 3m rows).

```
(queryset
    .values('owner', owner_name=F('owner__name'))
    .annotate(multi=Case(
        When(owner__in=Subquery(TrendData.objects
                                    .values('owner')
                                    .annotate(cnt=Count('owner'))
                                    .filter(cnt__gt=0)
                                    .values('owner')), 
             then=1),
        default=0,
        output_field=IntegerField())
    ) 
    .annotate(views = Case(
        When(multi=1,
             then=Sum(F('views') / date_delta)),
        default=Sum('views'),
        output_field=IntegerField())
    )
)
```

You can wrap the two annotations in one, but if you're reusing `multi` for several more annotations rather than just one as in my example, separating the two saves you from repeating the subquery for every annotation.

Comment: I've got same error as i mentioned to @Raydel comment above :(

Comment: hmm i tried once again it doesnt :(
but i guess i should mentioned that my django is 1.11 :/

Comment: I think the error was on my part, not due to Django versions. Take the above two queries for a spin if you like.

Answer (score 1):

First, I think this is wrong `owner_name=F('owner_id__name'`  it hsould be
`owner_name=F('owner__name'`.

If I understood, you want to annotate TrendData queryset with the amount of TrendData instances that have the owner.

You can use a [Subquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) to achieving that:

```
owner_td_count = Owner.objects.annotate(
    td_count=Count('trenddata_set')
).filter(
    id=OuterRef('owner_id')
).values('td_count')[:1]
```

Then annotate first by counting occurrences of owner_id:

```
queryset.annotate(
    owner_name=F('owner__name'),
    owner_id_count=Subquery(owner_td_count)   # How many DataTrend's have the owner with id=owner_id
    ).values('owner_name', 'owner_id').annotate(
        # ...
    )
)
```

Then you could in you Case/when construction:

```
Case(
    When(
        owner_id_count=1, then=F('views'), 
        default=F('views') / date_delta)),
        output_field=IntegerField() 
    )
)
```

Comment: this looks like it, however im getting an error :(
```django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot compute Sum('<Case: CASE WHEN <Q: (AND: ('owner_id_count__gt', 1))> THEN <CombinedExpression: F(views) / Value(2)>, ELSE Value(None)>'): '<Case: CASE WHEN <Q: (AND: ('owner_id_count__gt', 1))> THEN <CombinedExpression: F(views) / Value(2)>, ELSE Value(None)>' is an aggregate```

Comment: Perhaps the problem was that aggregates do no support lookups inside `When` expressions, I edit the answer in order to avoid the use of `__gt`  lookup on the `owner_id_count` aggregate inside the When expression.

Comment: You need to select some (non-unique) `values` *before* counting, otherwise the count will always be `1`.

Comment: @EndreBoth No, you don't. `owner_id`  could be a result of having a field `owner` which is a foreign key to another model. And the foreign key (can be but ...) is not guaranteed to be unique across the table.

Comment: But without `values`, you're grouping not only on `owner_id` (and `owner_name` which is neither here nor there), but also on the `id` of the model you're querying (here `TrendData`), leading to groups of one.

Comment: still getting this error :(
Im doing this
```queryset.annotate(
    owner_name=F('owner__name'),
    owner_id_count=Count('owner_id')  
    ).values('owner_name', 'owner_id').annotate(
views = Sum(Case(When(owner_id_count=1, then=F('views'), 
        views=F('views') / date_delta)),
        output_field=IntegerField()),
...
```

Comment: Not just that have the owner, but that queryset has more than 1 of the same owner.
Example : Queryset(owner_id : 1, views:10, likes:10... , owner_id : 2...,owner_id : 1..)
And if queryset has more than 1 of the same owner_id's (in this example there are 2 owners with id of 1 ) we divide by date_delta, else we just use default value from queryset. Sorry if my question is missleading, English is my 2nd language :(

Comment: Yes, then the updated answer is the solution, give it a try. Please take into account I've not tested this, this is an effort for pointing out you in the right direction.

Comment: still an error, changed ```'trenddata_set'``` to either trenda_data__owner_id and tried just ```trenddata```, both displaying same error :(
On ```trenddata_set``` he can't resolve a key for a field tried double underscore and got ```'Unsupported lookup 'set' for AutoField or join on the field not permitted'```

Comment: It's `trenddata`, not `trenddata_set` (and `owne*r*_td_count`). Other than that, it should work fine.